# Сhange the order of integration in the double integral

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have to change the order of integration in this double integral
[image]

I've decided to divide it in two similar areas D1 and D2

[image]

And I've got the following result
[image]

Can You chech it and state my probable mistakes. I have to be sure that the result is correct. Thanks

Comment: In the second double integral $\;y\in[-1,0]\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

$$\{(x,y)\mid0\lt x\lt1,x-1\lt y\lt1-x\}=\{(x,y)\mid x+|y|\lt1\}$$
$$\int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_{x-1}^{1-x}f(x,y)\mathrm dy=\int_{-1}^1\mathrm dy\int_0^{1-|y|}f(x,y)\mathrm dx$$